# How to get the variable of loop from Shell script to retrieve inside python script

Tags: python, linux, shell, dictionary

Sorry, I am new in python and I just have basic of Shell script/sh. I have two question.
1) How to get the variable of the loop from bash to retrieve inside python script?
2) How to keep in max key-value from many files to the same dictionary?

Those above questions are related.
Explanation: 
The main script is in the Shell script, where they will loop some Shell command and then run Python script for many **K**.

Eg:

```
#!/bin/sh

for a in K*
do
 echo $a
   # Loop to call the file.
   for i in 1 2 3 4 5
   do
      # Cut the row and column
      grep -v '^#' $a/result*.txt | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 6 | cat > pos.txt
   done
chmod a+wx pie1.py
./pie1.py $a/pos.txt $a/neg.txt

chmod a+wx max.py
./max.py $a/output1.py
```

So in max.py I have made a dictionary where it will save the key and the max value.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

#import pickle
from output1 import *
import subprocess

dicoMax = {}
# The Flist read from output1 that save all the Fscore for one File
dicoMax['K*']=max(Flist)
print(dicoMax)
```

I want to retrieve the **K* or a** variable from the Shell script as the key of dictionary inside max.py(python script) and lastly save all the key and max value for K* in one dictionary.

Tq.

Comment: This would probably be easier if you combined the functionality from the shell script and the python script into 1 script (probably python).

Comment: BTW, `chmod a+w` on a source file is a **horrid** idea: It means any user on your system, including system users like `nobody` used for daemons running completely untrusted code (ie. interfacing on the network with potentially hostile users) can modify your source file.

Comment: That said -- you're **already** passing `"$a/pos.txt"` and `"$a/neg.txt"` as arguments, so, well, you know how to pass arguments from shell (though the Python code you provide isn't retrieving them). Why can't you also pass `"$a"` itself **the exact same way**?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, I will modify my source code. I am new in python and shell so I did know the `"$a/pos.txt"` is passing as the argument and I was just think if we want to use the file we need to declare first like that and I already try. It succeeds passing  the argument, tq.

Comment: By the way -- also consider running your code through http://shellcheck.net/, and addressing the concerns it raises.

Comment: But now, I have a problem with my second question. I have tried `dicoMax.update({var:max(Flist)})` and `dicoMax.add(var, max(Flist)). But my dictionary list still one key:value pair for one loop of shell.

Comment: Of course. How would you expect it to behave otherwise?

Comment: Yes.  I am expect that my dictionary save all the max value from each K*. That means for every loop of Shell it will save all the max value in the same dictionary.  Is it possible?

Comment: To @CharlesDuffy tq. I had finally solved my problem. Yes!:-). I succeed in making a file to save all the dictionary and update the dictionary from the file.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways - You can pass it in as a command line argument (this would be the best way), or you could insert it into an environment variable (this is less clear)

Reading this [dive into python tutorial](http://www.diveintopython.net/scripts_and_streams/command_line_arguments.html) would be a good start.

Comment: A good answer is complete enough to stand alone without needing external links (not that having links is bad -- much to the contrary -- but the answer should still be good enough to be helpful without them). I'd at least suggest showing how to export a shell variable to a subprocess's environment (either with the `export` command, or with the single-line command-scoped syntax).

Answer (score 0):

For question 1 and 2:

```
#!/bin/sh

chmod a+wx pie1.py
for a in K*
do
 echo $a
   # Loop to call the file.
   for i in 1 2 3 4 5
   do
      # Cut the row and column
      grep -v '^#' $a/result*.txt | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 6 | cat > pos.txt
   done

./pie1.py $a/pos.txt $a/neg.txt
### passing the arguments or value through "$a"
./max.py "$a" $a/output1.py
done
```

So in python

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from output1 import *
from maxList import *
import sys  

dicoMax = {}
var = sys.argv[1] ###important
print var  
### Flist is the list of the Fscore that save in the output1 
### var is the key passing by Shell script
dicoMax[var]=max(Flist)
print(dicoMax)
### mList is the dictionary that save in the maxList file (mList must   
### be declared first) 
### it will update new key:value pair for new loop of Shell script
dicoMax.update(mList)
### Save the updated mList in maxList
a=open('maxList.py', 'w')
a.write("mList=%s\n" % dicoMax)
a.close()
```